# Possibility to upload content to Sharepoint via HTTP POST?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I was wondering if you could upload content (e.g. PDFs) via an HTTP POST to a Sharepoint site? The browser is doing nothing else, but I am having trouble configuring an application to do this. It posts successfully, but the content is lost. I can see that the POST is successful when looking at a packet capture.

Thanks for any advice,

MMF

Comment: Do you want to upload pdfs to SharePoint via HTTP POST?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I am aiming for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official demo:

```
'use strict';
    
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  // Check for FileReader API (HTML5) support.
  if (!window.FileReader) {
    alert('This browser does not support the FileReader API.');
  }
});

// Upload the file.
// You can upload files up to 2 GB with the REST API.
function uploadFile() {
  // Define the folder path for this example.
  var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '/shared documents';

  // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
  var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
  var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();

  // Get the server URL.
  var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

  // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
  // Get the local file as an array buffer.
  var getFile = getFileBuffer();
  getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {
    // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
    var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
    addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {
      // Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
      var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
      getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {
        // Change the display name and title of the list item.
        var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
        changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
          alert('file uploaded and updated');
        });
        changeItem.fail(onError);
      });
      getItem.fail(onError);
    });
    addFile.fail(onError);
  });
  getFile.fail(onError);

  // Get the local file as an array buffer.
  function getFileBuffer() {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
      deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
      deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
    return deferred.promise();
  }

  // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
  function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {
    // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
    var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
    var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

    // Construct the endpoint.
    var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
            "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
            "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
            serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);

    // Send the request and return the response.
    // This call returns the SharePoint file.
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
        type: "POST",
        data: arrayBuffer,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
          "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
        }
    });
  }

  // Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
  function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {
    // Send the request and return the response.
    return jQuery.ajax({
      url: fileListItemUri,
      type: "GET",
      headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    });
  }

  // Change the display name and title of the list item.
  function updateListItem(itemMetadata) {
    // Define the list item changes. Use the FileLeafRef property to change the display name.
    // For simplicity, also use the name as the title.
    // The example gets the list item type from the item's metadata, but you can also get it from the
    // ListItemEntityTypeFullName property of the list.
    var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}'}}",
        itemMetadata.type, newName, newName);

    // Send the request and return the promise.
    // This call does not return response content from the server.
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: itemMetadata.uri,
        type: "POST",
        data: body,
        headers: {
          "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
          "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "content-length": body.length,
          "IF-MATCH": itemMetadata.etag,
          "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
        }
    });
  }
}

// Display error messages.
function onError(error) {
  alert(error.responseText);
}
```

Source:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery

Comment: Thanks Amos! I actually have seen that one during my research, but I was looking at a pure HTTP POST variant. I can't change the application carrying out the upload.  I'll take it as - not possible - then.

Comment: You want to call http in spfx?